# How to sum data per month for a certain group?

Tags: r

I have searched for similar questions but none really ask what I need to know.

My question is how can I add the values of one column of every month for a certain group. My data set has 3 columns: Date, Province and Total reported infections. Now, I need the Total reported infections per month per province, and I am not quite sure how to do this.

I hope this makes sense

Here is a random sample of my data set:

```
ds <- structure(list(Date_of_publication = c("2021-04-05", "2020-09-16", 
"2020-05-21", "2021-04-11", "2020-04-05", "2021-04-23", "2021-06-17", 
"2021-07-25", "2021-02-08", "2021-01-17", "2021-02-25", "2021-01-16", 
"2021-07-11", "2021-08-10", "2020-11-02", "2020-07-04", "2020-03-01", 
"2021-01-22", "2021-07-25", "2021-01-14"), Province = c("Noord-Brabant", 
"Limburg", "Flevoland", "Noord-Holland", "Noord-Holland", "Zuid-Holland", 
"Utrecht", "Friesland", "Drenthe", "Flevoland", "Noord-Holland", 
"Overijssel", "Zuid-Holland", "Zuid-Holland", "Utrecht", "Noord-Holland", 
"Overijssel", "Limburg", "Gelderland", "Noord-Brabant"), Total_reported = c(66L, 
3L, 0L, 26L, 1L, 16L, 0L, 18L, 6L, 15L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 18L, 6L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract year and month from date using `format` and `sum` the `Total_reported` for each month and `Province`.

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

ds %>%
  group_by(year_month = format(as.Date(Date_of_publication), '%b %Y'), Province) %>%
  summarise(Total_reported = sum(Total_reported, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup

#  year_month Province      Total_reported
#   <chr>      <chr>                  <int>
# 1 Apr 2020   Noord-Holland              1
# 2 Apr 2021   Noord-Brabant             66
# 3 Apr 2021   Noord-Holland             26
# 4 Apr 2021   Zuid-Holland              16
# 5 Aug 2021   Zuid-Holland               8
# 6 Feb 2021   Drenthe                    6
# 7 Feb 2021   Noord-Holland             24
# 8 Jan 2021   Flevoland                 15
# 9 Jan 2021   Limburg                   18
#10 Jan 2021   Noord-Brabant             12
#11 Jan 2021   Overijssel                19
#12 Jul 2020   Noord-Holland              0
#13 Jul 2021   Friesland                 18
#14 Jul 2021   Gelderland                 6
#15 Jul 2021   Zuid-Holland               1
#16 Jun 2021   Utrecht                    0
#17 Mar 2020   Overijssel                 0
#18 May 2020   Flevoland                  0
#19 Nov 2020   Utrecht                    0
#20 Sep 2020   Limburg                    3
```

Or in base R -

```
aggregate(Total_reported ~ year_month + Province, 
      transform(ds, year_month = format(as.Date(Date_of_publication), '%b %Y')), 
      sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have accidently come across the fix by sheer luck.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

Infections <- read.csv("Infections_per_day.csv", sep = ";")
Infections <- Infections[, c(2,5,10)]

ds <- ds %>%
  mutate( month = month(Date_of_publication),
          year = year(Date_of_publication)) %>%
  group_by(month, year, Province) %>%
  summarise_if(is.integer, sum) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate("Date_of_publication" = paste(year, str_pad(month, 2, side = "left", pad = "0"), sep = "-")) %>%
  select(Date_of_publication, Province, Total_reported)
```

Comment: Nice! But maybe try `summarise` + `across` instead of `summarise_if``

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
ds$Date_of_publication <- as.Date(ds$Date_of_publication,format="%Y-%m-%d")
ds <- ds %>% mutate(Month=month(Date_of_publication))
output <- ds %>% group_by(Month,Province) %>% summarise(sum_Total_reported=sum(Total_reported)) %>% select(Province,sum_Total_reported)
```

output

```
   Month Province      sum_Total_reported
   <dbl> <chr>                      <int>
 1     1 Flevoland                     15
 2     1 Limburg                       18
 3     1 Noord-Brabant                 12
 4     1 Overijssel                    19
 5     2 Drenthe                        6
 6     2 Noord-Holland                 24
 7     3 Overijssel                     0
 8     4 Noord-Brabant                 66
 9     4 Noord-Holland                 27
10     4 Zuid-Holland                  16
11     5 Flevoland                      0
12     6 Utrecht                        0
13     7 Friesland                     18
14     7 Gelderland                     6
15     7 Noord-Holland                  0
16     7 Zuid-Holland                   1
17     8 Zuid-Holland                   8
18     9 Limburg                        3
19    11 Utrecht                        0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through following steps:

**1-extract month for each of dates you have**

you can use `month` function to do this as shown below:

```
ds$month <-  month(ymd(ds$Date_of_publication))
```

**2- Group your observations by province and month**

```
ds <- ds %>% group_by(Province, month) %>%  summarise(total=sum(Total_reported))
```

The result would be as what shown below:

```
   Province      month total
   <chr>         <int> <int>
 1 Drenthe           2     6
 2 Flevoland         1    15
 3 Flevoland         5     0
 4 Friesland         7    18
 5 Gelderland        7     6
 6 Limburg           1    18
 7 Limburg           9     3
 8 Noord-Brabant     1    12
 9 Noord-Brabant     4    66
10 Noord-Holland     2    24
11 Noord-Holland     4    27
12 Noord-Holland     7     0
13 Overijssel        1    19
14 Overijssel        3     0
15 Utrecht           6     0
16 Utrecht          11     0
17 Zuid-Holland      4    16
18 Zuid-Holland      7     1
19 Zuid-Holland      8     8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
ds %>% 
    mutate(Date_of_publication = ymd(Date_of_publication)) %>% 
    mutate(month = month(Date_of_publication, label = TRUE),
           year = year(Date_of_publication)) %>% 
    group_by(Province, year, month) %>% 
    summarise(n = sum(Total_reported), .groups = "drop") %>%
    arrange(year, month) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(month, n, fill=Province))+
    geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
    facet_wrap(~year)
```

```
   Province       year month     n
   <chr>         <dbl> <ord> <int>
 1 Overijssel     2020 Mrz       0
 2 Noord-Holland  2020 Apr       1
 3 Flevoland      2020 Mai       0
 4 Noord-Holland  2020 Jul       0
 5 Limburg        2020 Sep       3
 6 Utrecht        2020 Nov       0
 7 Flevoland      2021 Jan      15
 8 Limburg        2021 Jan      18
 9 Noord-Brabant  2021 Jan      12
10 Overijssel     2021 Jan      19
11 Drenthe        2021 Feb       6
12 Noord-Holland  2021 Feb      24
13 Noord-Brabant  2021 Apr      66
14 Noord-Holland  2021 Apr      26
15 Zuid-Holland   2021 Apr      16
16 Utrecht        2021 Jun       0
17 Friesland      2021 Jul      18
18 Gelderland     2021 Jul       6
19 Zuid-Holland   2021 Jul       1
20 Zuid-Holland   2021 Aug       8
```

[image]